# How to filter by date on Google Analytics dashboard widgets

Tags: google-analytics, widget

How can you filter a Google Analytics dashboard widget to only include items after a certain date?

The only options for filtering are:

- Exactly matching
- Regular Expression
- Begins With
- Ends With
- Containing

It is not clear from those options that it would be possible, and I can not find out what format the Date dimension is in, though it appears that the year is first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can do that.  Probably becouse the system searches on the dates at the top of the dashboard.   Just set the date in there and you will only get the results back after that date.

Date is a dimension thats why you are only allowed to use those filter options.  Metrics you would be alowed to do something like a grater then.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see the date range at the top! You are right that it is not possible to filter individual widgets in the way I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, though arguably not very effective.

If you're trying to see top level month/month metrics in a dashboard, you can create separate "Metric" widgets, select your desired metric/KPI, and filter by:

## "Month of Year" - "Containing" - "[# Month]"

Then, set your date range to All-Time, past year, or some time that encompasses the Months filtered in your widgets.

Here's an example of sessions JUST in the month of November:
[image]